# How to access the words saved in the device dictionary?

Tags: android, dictionary

I don't know if its possible or not but I checked the documentations, researched a lot and still can't find a way.

I just want to know if its possible to access the words one "add to dictionary" from the SoftKeyboard suggestion bar. I'm able to add words to the dictionary but don't know how to retrieve them.
I don't think there is any direct method to retrieve those words but there must be some way around.

I'll be very thankful any if anyone can provide the solution to the problem.

Comment: develop your own keyboard..

Comment: I thought on that but a custom keyboard wont work for me.

Comment: can't i just get those words ? @DhawalSodhaParmar

Comment: i don't think its possible for every keyboard. but you can check for Samsung device may be they allow it.

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar can you please flag the question

Comment: why?? what kind of flag needed??